# When does BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs.CheckResult throw an exception?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

The documentation for `BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs.CheckResult` says:

> Throws an exception if the background task completed event has reported an error.

I've tried making a background task that throws an exception in its `Run` method, but when I subscribe to its `Completed` event and call `CheckResult` when it completes, no exception is thrown.

When does `CheckResult` actually throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

It should work exactly as you have described: if an exception is thrown in `IBackgroundTask`'s `Run` method, then `BackgroundTaskCompletedArguments.CheckResult()` method throws an exception when you call it.

Make sure that your background task actually runs and that your app is in foreground otherwise `IBackgroundTaskRegistration.Completed` event is not raised at all.

If you want to try it out on a working exaple, download [Background task sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9) and make two modifications to it:

- In `Task\ServicingComplete.cs` add `throw new Exception();` at the very end of `Run` method.
- In `BackgroundTask\ServicingCompleteTask.xaml.cs` add `args.CheckResult();` at the beginning of `OnCompleted` method.

If you now run the app, register the task from the UI and trigger it from Visual Studio's `Debug Location` toolbar when the app is in foreground, you will notice that the `CheckResult()` call will throw an exception as expected.